# Can Zend_Soap_Client set custom user-agent?

Tags: php, zend-framework, user-agent, soap-client

I have Zend_Soap_Server. It should be tested. One issue - unit testing and development modes should work with different databases. It can be done via .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (.*) APPLICATION_ENV=development
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent testing APPLICATION_ENV=testing
```

It would work fine for me, I use Zend_Soap_Client as is for development/production mode, and add extra parameter for testing. There are no special changes in source code for testing support.
The issue - I can't set custom user-agent for ([Zend_Soap_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html)
It seems as this parameter isn't supported or isn't documented.
I tried to do the same thing via mod_rewrite and adding

```
new Zend_Soap_Client('...?wsdl&testing');
```

but it requires to change Zend_Soap_Server to support testing Query_String, otherwise soap-actions aren't reflected with 'testing' outside of wsdl. It's not good in my opinion.

I agree it's a bit more related with acceptance testing, not unit (I have tests for classes such as `$server->setClass('classWS')`), but anyway, I need it regardless of terminology.

So, what would work fine for me is something like:

```
new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl, array('useragent' => 'testing'));
```

in tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but it's a bit more complicated than just setting an option. The key is a *stream context*. The required function is [`stream_context_create()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) - please also have a look at ["HTTP context options"](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'testing'
    )
);
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl, array('stream_context' => $context));

// or set option after instatiation
$client->setStreamContext($context);
```

**EDIT:**

As the stream context user-agent seems to get overridden another option is to use the `user_agent`-option of [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) itself. But this is a little bit more complicated as this option is not exposed by `Zend_Soap_Client`.

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl);
$options = array_merge($client->getOptions(), array(
    'trace'      => true,
    'user_agent' => 'testing'
));
$soapClient = new Zend_Soap_Client_Common(array($client, '_doRequest'), $wsdl, $options);
$client->setSoapClient($soapClient);
```

The above code is more or less an extract of what happens in `Zend_Soap_Client::_initSoapClientObject()` which initializes the default `SoapClient` when no custom object is registered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately, I've got $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] => "PHP-SOAP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2" even if user_agent is defined via stream_context_create (I tried both your cases).
My guess, it's because:   
header  string
    Additional headers to be sent during request. Values in this option will override other values (such as User-agent:, Host:, and Authentication:).

May be Zend adds header option, but I'm not sure

Comment: Hi Alexey, I added another option you can try. It seems as if the user-agent passed in through a stream context gets overriden by the `SoapClient` itself.

Comment: Thank you again!
I realized that ['http']['user_agent'] option doesn't impact native php SoapClient (so, Zend_Soap_Client isn't a reason by itself).
I'm not sure is it desired behavior or not, but anyway I think it make sense me to just report to Zend team and ask about enabling 'user_agent' Zend_Soap_Client construct option (because it would work fine - I checked). Anyway, thanks for your solution - it work even if seems not so pretty!

Comment: My final checking (without Zend):

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'user_agent' => 'testing'
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,
    array(
        'context_stream' => $context // doesn't change user-agent
        //'user_agent' => 'testing' // uncomment - work as desired!
    )
);
...
So, I have no idea why Zend has forbidden this option.

Comment: This has been fixed in r18569 of the Zend Framework trunk and will be part of the next Framework releas (either 1.9.5 or 1.10.0).